# how to call functions of an apk through python script

Tags: java, android, python, api

I have many functions built in my apk (eg. Call, SMS, airplane mode etc.). I want to make a python script to run these functions in many combinations please suggest how to call these function in a python script.

Eg:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:012345678"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

I want to make a python script by which I call this java code and it runs on the phone and makes a call.

Comment: A good answer should show research effort; have you tried finding this out on your own? What things did you find? What went wrong?

Comment: Hi, @Ludwik I have added some more details please check.

Answer (score 2):

your question is not much clear , but here are few things which is needed while trying to call any APK

**Appium**

Appium  is needed in order to communicate with apps in phone from your preferred language .
You will find many links on net about setting up the appium on your environment

**Appium  Python client** 
This will allow to use appium library in python

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Appium-Python-Client/0.2

**Desired Capability** 
Desired capability tells the program about the target application and devices details . so if you want to test your application, you need to provide your details here

```
desired_caps[‘platformName’] = ‘Android’
desired_caps[‘platformVersion’] = ‘4.4’
desired_caps[‘deviceName’] = ‘A102’
desired_caps[‘app’] = ‘C:PyEditorAppium_ScrollTestsrcWitStatus.apk’
desired_caps[‘appPackage’] = ‘com.witmergers.getstatus’
desired_caps[‘appActivity’] = ‘.MainActivity’
```

for further details, you can refer

https://github.com/appium/python-client

The scope of your question is quite big, but at least this will give u a head start to move ahead